# Swift and JSON online url to display images

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

So this is the code that I am using to create my table view from scratch. My question is how can I parse an image if the image is of string (url) format?

```
class ArticleCell : UITableViewCell {
var article: Article? {
    didSet {
        articleTitle.text = article?.title
        //articleImage.image = article?.urlToImage
        descriptionTitle.text = article?.description
    }
}

private let articleTitle : UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.textColor = .black
    lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    lbl.textAlignment = .left
    return lbl
}()

private let descriptionTitle : UILabel = {
    let desclbl = UILabel()
    desclbl.textColor = .black
    desclbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
    desclbl.textAlignment = .left
    return desclbl
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(articleTitle)
    addSubview(descriptionTitle)
```

Because then what I would like to do is:

```
addsubview(articleImage)
```

I get an error as I am declaring an image but it is in a string format. Now, using storyboard is easy, but programmatically I have this issue.

Is it more understandable now? I am so sorry if I made confusion.

Comment: Certainly we can help. However, you haven't really asked a question.

Comment: I changed how I formatted the question

Comment: You need to download the image using the url you have, then you can show it. Just google "swift download image from url"